# Инструменты для редактирования контента (WordPress) заказчиком

Tags: wordpress

Выполняю первый проект на wordpress. Получилось интегрировать формы через contact-form-7. Получилось сделать карточки товаров через Woocommerce. Страницы создавал через шаблоны, то есть вверху файла .php писал такую запись:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Главная страница
Template Post Type: page
*/
?>
```

И тут внезапно заказчик спрашивает: "А как я могу внести изменения в содержимое? Например, текст поменять? Или изображения, видео?". Сказать, что вон есть раздел "Внешний вид", в нём подраздел "Редактор тем", выбирай нужный файл и корректируй - непрофессионально. В итоге оказалось, что при моей текущей квалификации вносить изменения в контент заказчик может только через меня. Мы решили попробовать так и поработать. То есть мне заказчик говорит вот тут текст надо убрать, вот тут надо заменить, вот тут надо добавить, а я вношу соответствующие правки. Это так неудобно! Как и для меня, разработчика, так и для заказчика.

Думаю, что читатели вопроса поняли мою проблематику.

Наверняка для CMS существует какая-то группа инструментов, которая позволяет настроить ВП таким образом, что бы заказчик сам мог потом и без веб-мастера вносить правки в контент. Что это за инструменты? Может это мой каприз, но ещё хотелось бы, что бы мне не приходилось переписывать с нуля вёрстку при этом.

Что сообщество может предложить на сейчас, на конец 2019 года? Какие из этих инструментов пользуются большим спросом нынче на рынке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advanced Custom Fields поможет вам создать быстро поля для все ваших кастомных полей

Comment: Да, в итоге именно ACF решил решил мой вопрос. Создаю группу полей, подключаю её к нужной странице, связываю каждое поле в вёрстке с нужными тегами, атрибутами или прочим, а дальше мой заказчик может сам вносить в этой странице свои данные.

Answer (score 1):

> Наверняка для CMS существует какая-то группа инструментов, которая
>   позволяет настроить ВП таким образом, что бы заказчик сам мог потом и
>   без веб-мастера вносить правки в контент. Что это за инструменты?

Этот инструмент называется CMS. В данном случае WоrdPress.
ВСЕ, абсолютно [все CMS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC) как раз дя того и созданы, чтобы без лазания в код можно было наполнять сайт содержимым.
В WоrdPress это делается не через "внешний вид", а в нужных ЗАПИСЯХ и СТРАНИЦАХ.

Таким образом "Страницы создавал через шаблоны, то есть вверху файла .php писал такую запись" сделано неверно и неправильно. Точнее неправильное применение этого механизма.